# How to import a utility function from a python module without unnecessary dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I need to use a utility function that exists in an external module I do not control. The module has many imports that are not used by the specific function I care about. I don't want to install those unnecessary dependencies (and especially not bloat my packages dependency list).

It [doesn't seem possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230840/how-to-import-a-class-from-a-module-without-importing-the-whole-module) to use the function without the imports. I wondered if it's possible to mock the module? I had briefly hoped this would work:

```
""" module_a """
import unused_module

def f():
  return something_of_value


""" module_b: needs to use module_a.f() but doesn't have unused_module installed. """
import mock_module as unused_module
global unused_module
import module_a

module_a.f()
```

But I couldn't inject my mock of `unused_module`. Is there a workaround I could use here?

Comment: Is it open source? Copy it out if it is.

Comment: Just to add, you should check the conditions in the license for the project before just copying the code if you are writing code for a company or similar

Comment: Moot point, the function I'm employing is very likely to change in the future so making a copy would be worse than dealing with the imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?  We're exploiting the module caching system, where modules only get imported once *and* get stored in `sys.modules` which is a dict.

##### utili.py (which I should have called `module_a.py`)

```
""" module_a """
import unused_module

def f():
  return "something_of_value"
```

Then the client code that needs to use your function.

##### user.py

```
import sys

#we're not really doing anything here, just 
#slotting in a fake entry into sys.modules 
#so that it wont bother to "reimport" unused_modules
sys.modules["unused_module"]  = 1

from utili import f

print(f"{f()=}")
```

#### output of executing user.py:

```
python user.py
f()='something_of_value'
```

And, to be clear, I don't have an actual `unused_module` anywhere, so the import will fail if `utili.py` is called first.

```
py utili.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/explore/test_384_mockmo/utili.py", line 2, in <module>
    import unused_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unused_module'
```

Things will also not go well if any code tries to use `unused_module` so your `f` definitely can't require its actual existence.  Ditto for any code that gets executed at the module load of `utili.py`.  You could however assign a mock of some sorts instead of the litteral `1`.